# Monotouch - iPad Simulator issue with UIPopoverController

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, uipopovercontroller

I'm getting the following error, only on the simulator and not on the iPad itself!

```
Monotouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown 
"Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSGenericException 
Reason: - [UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible."
```

Has anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: as Miguel answer, you have to create an instance variable for UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This causes the problem...*

```
private void GetPopsUps()
{           
UIPopoverController uipoc = new UIPopoverController(new PopController());
uipoc.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 300f);
uipoc.PresentFromRect (new RectangleF(0,0, 200, 300), this.View, 
UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, true);
}
```

*This solves it (for me)..*

```
UIPopoverController uipoc;
private void GetPopsUps()
{           
uipoc = new UIPopoverController(new PopController());
uipoc.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 300f);
uipoc.PresentFromRect (new RectangleF(0,0, 200, 300), this.View, 
UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you let the garbage collector remove the reference.

I would love to see how this is happening, so I could add a special case in the future, but for now, try keeping a reference to the UIPopover and UIPopoverController.

Comment: The Simulator runs the GC much more aggressively than on the actual device. This is to help catch GC issues on real devices with much lower memory capacity than on devices you might be testing on or in the simulator (since it will use the power your machine provides).

Comment: I got this problem in Device also